# How to click on monthly using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to click on monthly in trailing returns part of the dropdown but it seems i am missing on some basic part which I am not able to figure it.
Website :- "https://www.morningstar.com/stocks/xnas/jazz/trailing-returns"

'''

```
wd.get("https://www.morningstar.com/stocks/xnas/jazz/trailing-returns")
check=wd.find_element(By.XPATH,"//button[contains(@class,'mds-button__sal mds-button--secondary__sal mds-button--small__sal')]//span")
print(check)
```

'''

This always returns me daily tag under span class even-though i change it to monthly. [image]

Comment: Where in this code do you "change it to monthly"?

Comment: Have you tried to find `button` tag with `id=monthly`? Rather than use the `class`?

Comment: `check=wd.find_element(By.XPATH,'//span[@class="mds-list-group__item-text__sal"]')[1].click()`? Can you try this?

Comment: Use `//li[2]//span[contains(@class, 'mds-list-group__link__sal')]`

You need to take an `li` by the index of 2

Comment: In the screenshot provided when I Click on monthly only the span tag is changed to monthy i.e  <span>Monthly</span>, but when I am doing print to check which span tag is coming in it only points to <span>Daily</span>, you can use the above script to get the print output.